# Big Oh notation loop manipulation

Tags: big-o, nested-loops

If I had two nested loops where the outer had a big oh notation of `logn`
and the inner had one of `n` does that mean the overall notion would be `log2n`?
because since n changes every time the outer loop executes, then the inner loop is technically running `logn` times but it loops n times. I apologise if this question sounds stupid. This is how the loop looks like:

```
outer loop runs while n>0
   inner loops runs n times
   n=(1/4)n
```

I'm sorry if my formatting is off, I spent a few minutes trying to figure out how to use latex here and couldn't quite crack it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time complexity is `O(n)`:

```
First time, inner loop iterates n times
Second time, inner loop iterates n/4 times
Third time, inner loop iterates n/16 times
...
K'th time, inner loop iterates n/(4^k) times
```

Summing them up:

```
n + n/4 + n/16 + ... + n/4^k + ... + n/(4^log_4(n))
```

This is [sum of geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum) with:

```
a = n
r = 1/4
```

And it's sums is bounded by: `(n/3/4) = 4n/3` accorsing to the formula for `r < 1`

Comment: Thank you. So, just to be sure, the overall time complexity is `nlogn`?

Comment: Meaning the outer loop runs `logn` times

Comment: @DrewU No, as explicitly explained in the answer, time complexity if `O(n)`. Make sure you understand why.

Comment: Yes I understand the inner loop has a time complexity of O(n). I'm asking if the outer loop does indeed have a time complexity of O(logn)

Comment: thus would the overall complexity of the outer and the inner loop be O(nlogn)? time complexity of inner loop * time complexity of outer loop

Comment: @DrewU No, that's not how it works. The total time complexity is the number of iterations of the inner loop, which is `n + n/4 + n/16 + ... <4n/3`. Read the answer carefully and follow the analysis.